# how to give a onclick action in a EXTJS.?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am new to Extjs,I create a grid panel in extjs, with toolbar. I give a add button, in controller the button name is given. in view, i create a tool bar in create function, not in define. Using alias i create one name also, by using that widget name i used to call in controller, by using button action value give thew function foropen a new, but it notworking. If i use panel within init function in view part means it will not disply any panels.

and my coding is
     `Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    alias  : 'widget.toolbar',
    renderTo: document.body,
   items: [
        {
            itemId  : 'addtab',
            text: 'Add',
            iconCls: 'add',
            action: 'addtab'
          }]
})`
this is the view part. action here i given as addtab

and my controller is

```
init: function() {this.control({
 'toolbar button[itemId=grid-add]': {
            click: function(){
                top.addTab(true,"../medias/add","Media","common",0,'add');
            }
        }
})
```

button is working.. and my add page is also working fine. but the calling function that is cal by alias is not working. can anyone give the solution.
i want to give the function in controller file only.

thank you..

Comment: `itemId  : 'addtab',` -> `[itemId=grid-add]'`

Comment: thank yoyu @Evan Trimboli, that also i tryed already, its not working, if i use init component function means it disply nothing..

Comment: how about `toolbar button#grid-add`

Comment: no it is not working.. @JChap

Comment: while defining file i give the reference like this.. "{ref: 'Toolbar',   selector: 'toolbar'}," is write.??